# $\mathrm{CO_2}$ rate of deposition

Tags: thermodynamics

Parts of Antarctica average -127°F (-83°C). The freezing point of $\mathrm{CO_2}$ is -109.3 °F (-78.5 °C). If one could construct a large container at such a place shielded from the sun, would atmospheric $\mathrm{CO_2}$ be expected to freeze out inside the container? If so, what rate of deposition could be expected?

If practical, this might be a solution to the excess atmospheric $\mathrm{CO_2}$ problem. However, I suspect that the rate of deposition is too small, the energy cost of increasing it with extra pressure or other means is too large, and sundry engineering considerations mean it is not viable.

Comment: Can you give a source for the figure of $-83^\circ\mathrm{C}$ as a mean temperature? From some informal googling, it looks like there are recorded temperatures well below that, but I'm not finding anything that low quoted as an average. The lowest I can see is the daily mean temperature at [Vostok Station](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vostok_Station#Climate) in August, which is $-68.0^\circ\mathrm{C}$. If there were areas with annual averages lower than $-78.5^\circ\mathrm{C}$, one would probably expect to find deposits of solid $\mathrm{CO_2}$ there already.

Comment: What got me thinking about this was reading an online news article:http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2013/12/131210-coldest-place-on-earth-antarctica-science/

Comment: Hmm, there's something a bit fishy there - the article says "Antarctic regions are always cold, averaging a nippy -127°F (-83°C) and fluctuating only a few degrees up and down", but in fact $-127^\circ\mathrm{F}$ is $-88^\circ\mathrm{C}$, not -83. Sadly, I suspect this figure is just a mistake on the part of the author.

Comment: It seems like some of the coldest places have been measured by satellite, not directly by people. Perhaps there are already CO2 deposits in some places.

Comment: The main figure in the Nat Geo article is correct though - they did measure a temperature of $-93^\circ\mathrm{C}$ by remote sensing. But that's just a momentary thing - the average temperature is much higher, so any CO2 formed will sublime again later, especially during the summer. If the temperatures *regularly* get that low, I suppose it might be possible to store the resulting dry ice in insulated containers, preventing it from turning back to gas. But my intuition says this probably can't be done on a large scale.

Comment: [It's been suggested](http://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/abs/10.1175/JAMC-D-12-0110.1). I don't know how seriously the suggestion has been taken, though Googling finds lots of rferences to this paper.

Comment: If the average temperature is indeed higher than the freezing point of CO2 then some energy input, possibly from solar panels, would be required to maintain the CO2 frozen during the parts of the year during which higher temperatures prevail. This energy input might not be so large, however, assuming good insulation and a small temperature differential. Oh well, so much for saving the planet!

Comment: That's basically what the paper says that John Rennie linked to - they propose a liquid nitrogen cooling system, which requires energy input, but it's much more efficient than doing it in a warmer climate where you have to cool the air a lot more.

Comment: That's an interesting paper. Thanks for the link. In light of this paper, we can consider the question addressed.

Comment: Despite widespread misconceptions, there is nothing such as "excess atmospheric CO2 problem". The economically and ecologically optimum concentration of CO2 would be around 4,000 ppm. The current concentration is 10 times lower than that. The Earth's ecosystem are CO2-starving, in a technical sense, but of course they got adapted to that. However, most existing plant species are unable to adapt to concentrations below 150 ppm. Dropping below that value would pretty much mean the end of life on Earth, at least temporarily.

Comment: yes, dear, keep taking the tablets.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation but I am not taking any tablets.

Comment: @LubošMotl - Your argument is a red herring as nobody is suggesting to drop CO$_2$ to below 150 ppm.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether he actually wants it or not. If someone is proposing to deliberately manipulate with the CO2 level, it is a good idea to know which levels are safe and which levels are not, isn't it? I was just explaining that the OP is wrong when he says that the CO2 concentration is excessive. It's far closer to the minimum level compatible with life than to high levels that would be dangerous because they are high.

Answer (score 1):

The atmospheric concentration of carbon dioxide is about 400ppm, or about 0.0004 atmospheres at sea level (less in central Antarctica).  According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_dioxide_data), the saturated vapor pressure at this pressure is a little below -140 ºC.  This means that atmospheric $CO_2$ will not freeze anywhere in Antarctica (except inside the BICEP2 telescope).

Sorry about that.